# How to connect to Mariadb using C language in Windows 10?

Tags: c, mariadb

Windows version - 10

gcc version - 6.3.0

MariaDB version - 10.9

Also, I have installed the c\c++ extension in visual code.

I am using Visual Code to run the below C code but facing the error maybe they are a problem with the linker. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.9\include\mysql\server\mysql.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MYSQL* con = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (con == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        exit(1);
    }

    if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "USERNAME", "PASSWD",
        NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (mysql_query(con, "CREATE DATABASE testdb"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(1);
    }

    mysql_close(con);
    exit(0);
}
```

**Command**

`gcc  .\mysqlcon.c -o mysqlcon -L"C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.9\lib\" -l"libmariadb.lib"`

**Error**

```
PS C:\Users\Pan\Desktop\Mysqlcon> gcc .\mysqlcon.c -o mysqlcon -L"C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.9\lib\" -l"libmariadb.lib"
C:\Users\Pan\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYX5KZT.o:mysqlcon.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `mysql_init@4'
C:\Users\Pan\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYX5KZT.o:mysqlcon.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `mysql_error@4'        
C:\Users\Pan\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYX5KZT.o:mysqlcon.c:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect@32'
C:\Users\Pan\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYX5KZT.o:mysqlcon.c:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `mysql_error@4'        
C:\Users\Pan\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYX5KZT.o:mysqlcon.c:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `mysql_close@4'        
C:\Users\Pan\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYX5KZT.o:mysqlcon.c:(.text+0x101): undefined reference to `mysql_query@8'       
C:\Users\Pan\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYX5KZT.o:mysqlcon.c:(.text+0x113): undefined reference to `mysql_error@4'       
C:\Users\Pan\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYX5KZT.o:mysqlcon.c:(.text+0x13d): undefined reference to `mysql_close@4'
C:\Users\Pan\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYX5KZT.o:mysqlcon.c:(.text+0x157): undefined reference to `mysql_close@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

**Include file:**

`#include "C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.9\include\mysql\server\mysql.h"`

This should generate a compilation error, since by default the MSI installer installs mysql.h in directory `C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.9\include\mysql`.

Preferable you should include only mysql.h and specify the include directory instead.

**Client library**

The libraries shipped with MariaDB Server (and MariaDB Connector/C) are intended to use with VisualStudio compiler, not for MinGW.

If you want to build with msys/gcc, you have to install the MariaDB client libraries via pacman.

Comment: How can I install the MariaDB client libraries via pacman?